# NetBeans to MySQL Connection

Tags: mysql, netbeans

I have a student trying to connect the latest version of NetBeans with mySQL 2019. Even after installing mySQL, we're unable to find the mysqld file required to make the connection.

Can anyone out there help?

Thanks!

Comment: that is not enough information, what operating system are you using. look for ifa isnatll guide

Comment: Windows 10. We are following the instructions here: https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/mysql.html   and are getting stuck on Step 6.  Thanks.

Comment: it is still very confusing which admin tool do you use.if you have none try mysql workbench or https://alternativeto.net/software/mysql-workbench/ you find to all of them a video tutorials.